# How Do I convert Stream<QuerySnapshot> to List<myObject>

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm querying Firestore and getting a Stream back as a Stream of QuerySnapshots. I need to map the included Documents in the stream to a List of objects.

The code below doesn't work (obviously)...maybe I'm just looking at this entirely wrong.

```
  List<UserTask> getUserTaskList() {
    List<UserTask> list;

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = 
      Firestore.instance.collection('userTasks').snapshots();
    stream.listen((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        UserTask userTask = UserTask(
            doc.data['id'],
            doc.data['Description'],
            etc...);

        list.add(userTask);
      });
    });

    return list;
  }
```

With the code above, since it doesn't wait for the entire stream (or any of it actually), list is always returned as null. In short, how do I convert my stream to a List?

Note: I'm pretty new to the world of Dart, so go easy on me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, think about this: this function has to return very quickly. All functions do, otherwise UI would hang. However, you are expecting the function to return something that comes from the internet. It takes time. The function has to return. There is no way for a function to simply do a network request and return you the result. Welcome to the world of [asynchronous programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=17).

Furthermore, the stream you have is not a stream of `DocumentSnapshot`s (which you can convert to `UserTask`s), but a stream of `QuerySnapshot`s (which you can convert to `List<UserTask>`s). Notice the plural there. If you simply want to get all your `UserTask`s once, you should have a `Future` instead of a `Stream`. If you want to repeatedly get all your `UserTask`s after each change, then using a `Stream` makes sense.

Since you said you want to get a `List<UserTask>`, I'm assuming you want to get the collection of `UserTask`s only once.

Here's what your code becomes in this light:

```
  Future<List<UserTask>> getUserTaskList() async {

    QuerySnapshot qShot = 
      await Firestore.instance.collection('userTasks').getDocuments();

    return qShot.documents.map(
      (doc) => UserTask(
            doc.data['id'],
            doc.data['Description'],
            etc...)
    ).toList();
  }

  main() async {
    List<UserTask> tasks = await getUserTaskList();
    useTasklist(tasks); // yay, the list is here
  }
```

Now if you really wanted to use a stream, here's how you could do it:

```
  Stream<List<UserTask>> getUserTaskLists() async {

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = 
      Firestore.instance.collection('userTasks').snapshots();

    return stream.map(
      (qShot) => qShot.documents.map(
        (doc) => UserTask(
            doc.data['id'],
            doc.data['Description'],
            etc...)
      ).toList()
    );
  }

  main() async {
    await for (List<UserTask> tasks in getUserTaskLists()) {
      useTasklist(tasks); // yay, the NEXT list is here
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Gazihan. Unfortunately, when I tried that code, I got the following exception:  

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'MappedListIterable<DocumentSnapshot, UserTask>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<UserTask>>')  

at the line "return.qshot.documents.map(..."

Comment: Right, I always forget the `toList()`... I edited the code, could you try again?

Comment: Thanks @Gazihan! That appears to be working perfectly :) I'm just not completely sure due to a bug in my code that has come up now which is totally unrelated. One of the fields I'm trying to map is a Firestore Timestamp, and I'm trying to put it in my model as a DateTime. I'm sure that answer is around here somewhere. Then I can fully test it. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW - I changed "get()" to "getDocuments()" You may want to update your answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I do use `TimeStamp`/`DateTime`. Incoming from Firebase: `Timestamp ts = d["date"]; date = ts.toDate();`. Outgoing to Firebase: `Timestamp.fromDate(date)`. Hope it helps!

Comment: You deserver a medal! Thank you  :)

Comment: getDocuments() has been deprecated for get() https://stackoverflow.com/a/68302244/7556522
Furthermore, you won't need doc.data()['property'] you can change it to doc['property']

Comment: As per October 2022, if you add "async" to the function, it gives the error "Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'". For the rest, superb!

Answer (score 0):

2023. Something like this

```
 Future<Stream<List<UserTask>>>
      get getUserTaskLists async {
    var str = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userTasks')
        .snapshots();

    return str.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) =>
            UserTask.fromJson(doc.data())

// or UserTask(
//             doc.data['id'],
//            doc.data['Description'],
//            etc...)

         ) .toList());
  }
```

So, i used a getter, but it may be a function(method) Future<Stream<List>> getUserTaskLists();