# How do I convert a Firestore Timestamp to a Dart DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm mapping a QuerySnapshot from Firestore to one of my Dart classes. One of the fields returned is stored as a Timestamp in Firestore and I need to map it to a DateTime in my model.

In the code snippet below, it errors out on 'dueDate' since UserTask.dueDate is a DateTime object.

```
return querySnapshot.documents
    .map((doc) => UserTask(
          doc.data['id'],
          doc.data['dueDate'],
        ))
    .toList();
```

I know I can do it in 2 steps like this: Timestamp ts = d["date"]; date = ts.toDate(); due to the answer here: [How Do I convert Stream<QuerySnapshot> to List<myObject>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152017/how-do-i-convert-streamquerysnapshot-to-listmyobject). But how would I do it in the scenario above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either:

```
return querySnapshot.documents
    .map((doc) => UserTask(
          doc.data['id'],
          doc.data['dueDate'].toDate(),
        ))
    .toList();
```

or

```
return querySnapshot.documents
    .map((doc) {
        var ts = doc.data['dueDate'];
        var date = ts.toDate();
        return UserTask(
          doc.data['id'],
          date,
        );})
    .toList();
```

Comment: Thanks @richard. The first option wouldn't work. The second option worked when I did it this way:  

return querySnapshot.documents
    .map((doc) {
        TimeStamp ts = doc.data['dueDate'];
        return UserTask(
          doc.data['id'],
          ts.toDate(),
        );})
    .toList();