# Flutter can't convert Firestore Timestamp to DateTime

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to convert Firestore Timestamp to DateTime in Flutter I'm getting always an error, tried all of the solutions, none worked ( last tried [How to print Firestore timestamp as formatted date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627888/how-to-print-firestore-timestamp-as-formatted-date-and-time))

Here's my code below;

**Code**

```
factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserModel(
      name: map['name'],
      email: map['email'],
      username: map['username'],
      registerDate:
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['registerDate'] * 1000),
      id: map['id'],
      imageUrl: map['imageUrl'],
      cvUrl: map['cvUrl'],
      phoneNumber: map['phoneNumber'],
      education: Education.fromMap(map['education']),
      location: Location.fromMap(map['location']),
      lookingForIntern: map['lookingForIntern'],
    );
  }
```

**Error**

```
'Timestamp' has no instance method '*'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Timestamp'
```

Converted DateTime to Timestamp, and changed

```
registerDate:
              DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['registerDate'] * 1000),
```

to

```
registerDate:map['registerDate']
```

now getting error below;

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Timestamp'
```

but `print(map['registerDate'])` prints `Timestamp(seconds=1632412800, nanoseconds=0)`

Comment: This bug seems out there for a long time, The solution would be having the TimeStamp in model instead of the DateTime.

Comment: @EngineSense Can you please check the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/dart-flutter-converting-timestamp) if it answers your question?

Comment: nope, not related to the issue! thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a Firestore Timestamp to a Dart DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153562/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-timestamp-to-a-dart-datetime)

Comment: I switched my DateTime variable to 'dynamic' then converted it to DateTime in my UI using https://pub.dev/packages/date_format this package. But no, you can't convert Timestamp to DateTime directly, really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package to handle the problem-

https://pub.dev/packages/date_format

```
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';


     DateTime datetime = stamp.toDate();
        var time = formatDate(datetime, [hh, ':', nn, ' ', am]);
```

Comment: unfortunately not related with problem

Answer (score 0):

I have this firebase function that is returning a TimeStamp (`admin.firestore.Timestamp`) in the field `dueDateLatestRental`:

```
 return {
                    data: { 'rental': null, 'hash': null, 'dueDateLatestRental': dueDateLatestRental },
                    status: 403,
                    message: itemStatus
```

In my flutter code I'm parsing the timestamp like this:

```
try {
          dynamic dueDateLatestRental = result.data['data']['dueDateLatestRental'];
          final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(dueDateLatestRental) as Map<String, dynamic>;
          DateTime dueDateLatestRentalString = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data['_seconds'] * 1000).toLocal();
          String formattedDueDate = formatDate(dueDateLatestRentalString, [dd, '.', mm, '.', yyyy, ' ', HH, ':', nn]);
          logger.i('addRental result: $formattedDueDate');
            QuickAlert.show(
              context: context,
              type: QuickAlertType.error,
              title: 'Nicht verfügbar',
              text:
              'Das Teil ist bis zum $formattedDueDate ausgeliehen.',
              confirmBtnText: 'Okay',
              onConfirmBtnTap: () async {
                log("Box was not opened");
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },);
            return null;
        } catch (e) {
          logger.e("Error: could not parse the dueDateLatestRental");
          QuickAlert.show(
            context: context,
            type: QuickAlertType.error,
            title: 'Nicht verfügbar',
            text:
            'Das Teil ist bereits ausgeliehen. Bitte warte ein paar Tage.',
            confirmBtnText: 'Okay',
            onConfirmBtnTap: () async {
              log("Box was not opened");
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          );
          return null;
        }
```

I think it's safer to wrap this in a `try/catch`, because there are many ways how this could brake over time (e.g. me changing something in the database structure)

This is the resulting Alert Dialog:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

There are  different ways this can be achieved based on different scenario, see which of the following code fits your scenario.

1. ```
   map['registerDate'].toDate()
   ```
2. ```
   (map["registerDate"] as Timestamp).toDate()
   ```
3. ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['registerDate'].millisecondsSinceEpoch);
   ```
4. ```
   Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['registerDate'].millisecondsSinceEpoch).toDate();
   ```
5. Add the following function in your dart file.

   ```
   String formatTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
     var format = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // <- use skeleton here
     return format.format(timestamp.toDate());
   }
   ```

   call it as `formatTimestamp(map['registerDate'])`

Answer (score 0):

- datetime is to store the current time zone of the server. The timestamp type is to convert the current time of the server to UTC (world time) for storage
- you can set Firestore document arguments type to int

```
  @JsonKey(fromJson: timeFromJson, toJson: timeToJson)
  DateTime fileCreateTime;

  static DateTime timeFromJson(int timeMicroseconds) =>
      Timestamp.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timeMicroseconds).toDate().toLocal();
  static int timeToJson(DateTime date) =>
      Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(date.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch)
          .microsecondsSinceEpoch;
```