# "The method 'getDocuments' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseReference'." Flutter - Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i am have some  difficulties with saving my list of items inside a function as i do get an error "The method 'getDocuments' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseReference'." I don't have any clue how to fix it maybe someone could be so kind and explain what I'm doing wrong.

**Here is function code snippet**

```
getItemStreamSnapshots() async {
var data = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child("Book")
    .getDocuments();

setState(() {
  _allResults = data.documents;
});
searchResultsList();
return "complete";
}
```

**Here's how my DB looks like**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`DatabaseReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference-class.html) does not have a `getDocuments()` method. You should either use the [`once()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) method or the [`onValue`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onValue.html) property, if you want to read the data corresponding to the `DatabaseReference`.

You will find more details on how to use the Realtime Database with Flutter in the two following articles: ["How to use Firebase realtime database with Flutter"](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-realtime-database-with-flutter-ebd98aba2c91) and ["How to use Firebase Queries In Flutter"](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-queries-in-flutter-361f21005467).

Comment: Thank you for you time, i got the point of **DatabaseReference**. I was following tutorial where this part of code was done with **Firestore.instance**, as its not supported on newer versions.  But in the end it didn't worked out for me ether.

Comment: Use FirebaseFirestore.instance instead

Answer (score 3):

### Since 0.14.0 Query

**DEPRECATED: Calling getDocuments() is deprecated in favor of get().**

BREAKING: getDocuments/get has been updated to accept an instance of GetOptions (see below).

NEW: Query methods can now be chained.

NEW: It is now possible to call same-point cursor based queries without throwing (e.g. calling endAt() and then endBefore() will replace the "end" cursor query with the endBefore).

NEW: Added support for the limitToLast query modifier.

link: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog#0140